# Metric (TFM) file not found, Fond T2A at 12pt

Tags: bibliographies, cyrillic

I am trying to compile a document of class article. There are Cyrillic letters in some references I would like to cite as there is not English translation for the title or journal name of some of my sources.
I have compiled a minimal example which in my case throws the error: `Font T2A/cmr/m/n/12=larm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \babel@aux{russian}{}`

I run TexLive 2023 with TexStudio 4.6.3 on Linux Mint.

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.6cm, right=2.9cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = ext-authoryear, giveninits=true, uniquename = init, isbn = false, url = false, eprint = false, doi = false, dashed = false, uniquelist = minyear, maxcitenames = 2, minbibnames = 7, maxbibnames = 8, backend = biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
This is some text and I cite stuff \parencite{Tsvelev1981}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In my file `ref.bib` it says:

```
@Article{Tsvelev1981,
  author       = {Tsvelev},
  journaltitle = {Бюллетень Московского общества испытателей природы (Bulletin of the Moscow Society of Natural Scientists)},
  title        = {Veronicas (\textit{Veronica} \textsc{L.}) of the affinity of \textit{Veronica spicata} \textsc{L.} and some problems of the phylogenesis of the genus},
  year         = {1981},
  number       = {6},
  pages        = {82-92},
  volume       = {86},
}
```

I believe there are some similar questions out there. As far as I have seem most people try to use a mix of Cyrillic and Latin alphabets in their actual text and do not import mixed entries with their bibliography. I am not sure whether this makes a difference.
[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/error-in-tex-live-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found) suggests installing `texlive-fonts-recommended` may be a fix. I have this package installed. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278372/citing-russian-article-with-texmakerwindows-provides-an-error) asks to mark up the bibliography entries but used `natbib`. I have tried:

```
@Article{Tsvelev1981,
  author       = {Tsvelev},
  journaltitle = {\foreignlanguage{russian}{Бюллетень Московского общества испытателей природы} (Bulletin of the Moscow Society of Natural Scientists)},
  title        = {Veronicas (\textit{Veronica} \textsc{L.}) of the affinity of \textit{Veronica spicata} \textsc{L.} and some problems of the phylogenesis of the genus},
  year         = {1981},
  number       = {6},
  pages        = {82-92},
  volume       = {86},
}
```

However, this does not solve my problem. Is the `\foreignlanguage` command the way to go? Is there another package I need to install? I am stumped.

Comment: If it's just about the missing fonts (I can't test because `biblatex` fails) you might just need `tlmgr install collection-langcyrillic`. However, not also that much as the *last* encoding declared in `fontenc` is the default one, also the *last* language given to `babel` is the default one. With your current setup `russian` is the main language.

Comment: Hello, `collection-langcyrillic` is already installed. Changing the order of `babel'` and `fontenc` (`\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}`) arguments yields a different error message: `Command \CYRB unavailable in encoding T1.` Which I think means, LaTex is trying to apply the T1 encoding to the Cyrillic letters.

Comment: You've requested `russian` as the default language for `babel`. Generally better to pass language options to your class, too.

Answer (score 1):

Using modern OpenType/TrueType (OTF/TTF) Unicode fonts, instead of legacy fonts/encodings, makes things easier.

For example, Noto Serif has both Latin and Cyrillic in it.

[image: example]

Note that Biblatex/Biber can understand and apply `polyglossia`/`babel` language settings for an entry via the langid= field in the bibentry.

Note also that translations and comments can be stored as annotations in the bibentry (or in external files if there are many of them).

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Tsvelev1981,
  author       = {Tsvelev},
  journaltitle = {Бюллетень Московского общества испытателей природы (Bulletin of the Moscow Society of Natural Scientists)},
  title        = {Veronicas (\textit{Veronica} \textsc{L.}) of the affinity of \textit{Veronica spicata} \textsc{L.} and some problems of the phylogenesis of the genus},
  date         = {1981},
  number       = {6},
  pages        = {82-92},
  volume       = {86},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.6cm, right=2.9cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = ext-authoryear, giveninits=true, uniquename = init, isbn = false, url = false, eprint = false, doi = false, dashed = false, uniquelist = minyear, maxcitenames = 2, minbibnames = 7, maxbibnames = 8, backend = biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is some text and I cite stuff \parencite{Tsvelev1981}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```