How may one obtain Cyrillic letters in the bibliography?
See my question yesterday for context: How to obtain Cyrillic letters with polyglossia and main font TeX Gyre Pagella?
I tried using the following bibliography entry, and it gives many errors:
@book{Kovalevskaya1951,
    author = {\begin{russian}Ковалевская, С. В.\end{russian}},
    title = {\begin{russian}Воспоминания и письма\end{russian}},
    date = {1951},
    editor = {\begin{russian}Нечкина, М. В.\end{russian}},
    commentator = {\begin{russian}Штрайха, С. Я.\end{russian}},
    publisher = {\begin{russian}Издательство Академии Наук СССР\end{russian}},
    location = {\begin{russian}Москва\end{russian}},
}

How may the bibliography entry be written so as to compile with the Russian text?

Please don't use quotes for code.  Use code for code, so that it keeps the formatting.

@Teepeemm I do not understand your request. Please edit.

Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278591/110998 helps

Since you tag with biblatex…
\begin{filecontents*}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Kovalevskaya1951,
    language={russian},
    langid={russian},
    author = {Ковалевская, С. В.},
    title = {Воспоминания и письма},
    date = {1951},
    editor = {Нечкина, М. В.},
    commentator = {Штрайха, С. Я.},
    publisher = {Издательство Академии Наук СССР},
    location = {Москва},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{fontspec} % loaded automatically by 'unicode-math'

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[autolang=langname]{biblatex}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{russian,greek}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMbfcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Tempora}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{Tempora}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[range={cal, bfcal}]
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}[range=]

\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

%\newfontfamily{\fcyc}{cyklop}
%\newfontfamily{\falg}{AlgolRevived}[Scale=1.5,Color=red]
%\newfontfamily{\fsong}{FandolSong}
%\newfontfamily{\QTBrushStroke}{QTBrushStroke}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

test

\begin{greek}
γηκηασδκλφ
\end{greek}

\begin{russian}
гчйкгчй
\end{russian}

\cite{Kovalevskaya1951}

\printbibliography
    
\end{document}



Great! Incidentally, I also got the warnings Font shape `TU/LinLibertine_R.otf(0)/m/it' undefined and Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal There's no reference to Libertine in my code…

Right, and the warning had another origin:  It disappeared after I deleted the at this point seemingly superfluous \newfontfamily\russianfont{LinLibertine_R.otf}.
